# I've written a Lex program for identifying tokens but while I'm running it it's showing an error

Tags: flex-lexer, lex

**My Code:**

```c
%{
    #include<stdio.h>
%}

%%

"int"|"char"|"double"|"void"|"main" {printf("\n%s is a keyword",yytext);}

^[a - z A - Z _][a - z A - Z 0 - 9 _] * {printf("\n%s is an identifier",yytext);}

^[-+]?[0-9]* {printf(}\n%s is an integer",yytext);}

^[-+]?[0-9]*[.][0-9]+$ {printf("\n%s is a floating number",yytext);}

"+"|"-"|"*"|"/"|"%"|"//" {printf("\n%s is an arithmetic operator",yytext);}

">"|"<"|">="|"<="|"="|"=="|"<>" {printf("\n%s is a relational operator",yytext);}

.;

%%

int yywrap()
{
  return 1;
}

main()
{
  printf("Enter a String:\n");
  yylex();
}
```

This is the Code I've written. I'm getting an error while compiling it and I'm not sure what it is. Can you please take a look at it and say how to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: And, as a general rule, put `\n` at the *end* of a printf format, not at the beginning (unless you're will definitely need to write more information on the same line).

Comment: Please, format your code, so it is easy to read by others. We did it for you the last time but it doesn't mean it isn't your responsibility. Here is a guide on how to do it: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: @rici I'm new to Lex. And I'm trying my best to solve Lex programs. I ran my code in FLEX  Windows compiler and it just showed something like EOF is encountered in an action. It didn't give a detailed explanation of the error at all. So then I tried running it on Ubuntu, it showed something like invalid operands to binary and expecting ';' before '{' token and invalid suffix "_" on integer constant. I didn't understand what these errors meant and what's wrong with my code.

Comment: You should edit the description of the problem into the question so future readers don't need to dig though comments. I should be more specific about formatting the code. I've also meant proper indentation and removing redundant empty lines. You could also go an extra mile and mark is as language C. There is no syntax highlighting for lex but C tends to work well. We are quite strict about such things because Stack Overflow is supposed to repository of knowledge that allows someone with similar problem easily find your question and get the solution without having to ask a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't compile because there is a missing `"` in line `^[-+]?[0-9]* {printf(}\n%s is an integer",yytext);}` (at the beginning of the `printf`'s argument).

Flex says it found an EOF which means "End Of File". It found an "opening" `"` and it was looking for a matching closing `"` but it encountered end of the file first.

---

You should also pay attention to whitespaces in lex patterns.
Those two are not two are *not* equivalent:

```
^[a - z A - Z _][a - z A - Z 0 - 9 _] *
```

```
^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I see what mistake I made now.